# Python: calculating the 2 and 3 quartiles per group in a dataset

Tags: pandas, iqr

I have the following dataframe:

```
df =
code count
A    1
A    2
A    3
A    4
B    7
B    8
B    9
B    10
```

I want to produce the 25 and 75 quartiles per code:

```
code 25QT 75QT
A    2.5   3.5
B    8.5   9.5
```

Comment: Can you double check your values and eventually break down the calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`groupby.quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html), then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df.groupby('code')['count'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack()
```

Output:

```
      0.25  0.75
code            
A     1.75  3.25
B     7.75  9.25
```

With the format:

```
out = (df.groupby('code')['count']
         .quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack()
         .rename(columns=lambda x: f'{int(x*100)}QT')
         .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
  code  25QT  75QT
0    A  1.75  3.25
1    B  7.75  9.25
```